Problem of difference quotient : $\displaystyle\sum_{B\subseteq A} (-1)^{\mathrm{card}(B)} \cdot {{100+s(B)}\choose {\mathrm{card}(A)}}$
For any finite set $B⊂\mathbb N$, we note $\mathrm{card}(B)$ its cardinality as well as $s(B)$ the sum of its elements, and $A=\{1,2,\ldots,10\}$. Calculate :
$\displaystyle\sum_{B\subseteq A} (-1)^{\mathrm{card}(B)} \cdot {{100+s(B)}\choose {\mathrm{card}(A)}}$
And we have a hint :
Generalize the following formula :
$\Delta_h^nf(x) = \frac{1}{h^n} \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{n-i} \cdot {n\choose i} \cdot f(x+ih)$
With expression of the type : $\Delta_{h_1}\Delta_{h_2}\ldots\Delta_{h_n}f$
($(\Delta_h f)(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$ is the first difference quotient)
I tried to generalize this formula but every time it's wrong.

We let $A = \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ and set ourselves the task to evaluate
$$\sum_{B\subseteq A} (-1)^{\mathrm{card}(B)}
\times {n^2 + s(B)\choose \mathrm{card}(A)}.$$
We have from first principles that this sum is given by
$$[z^n] (1+z)^{n^2} \prod_{q=1}^n (1-(1+z)^q)
\\ = (-1)^n [z^n] (1+z)^{n^2} 
\prod_{q=1}^n (qz+\cdots+qz^{q-1}+z^q).$$
The product term has the property that
$$\prod_{q=1}^n (qz+\cdots+qz^{q-1}+z^q) =
n! z^n + \cdots + z^{n(n+1)/2}.$$
We conclude with
$$(-1)^n [z^n] (1+z)^{n^2} (n! z^n + \cdots)
= (-1)^n n! [z^0] (1+z)^{n^2} = (-1)^n n!.$$

How do you go from the 1st line to the 2nd line ?

Use ${n\choose k} = [z^k] (1+z)^n,$
